# How does someone even begin to code something like this? What are the ideas/thoughts behind this?

Tags: graphics

I recently came across this website on http://nkwiatek.com/ and it totally blew my mind.  How does someone begin to program something like that smokey/fluid effect?  Another thing that I can't even begin to conceptualize is a visualizer for a music program.

I only have two years of programming experience on my back but I believe I can see (well, at least I think I can) the vague ideas behind code that goes into various programs and what those programs require. However, programs that create abstract visual renderings (for lack of better words), such as the site I linked to or visualizers, completely baffle me when I try to think of how something like that is done.

For an answer, I'm looking for a pretty high level definition of the program, but low enough that it includes coding concepts and ideas that I can further research.
Because this question isn't exactly as 'concrete' as some of the other questions on this site, an appropriate answer might include:

- Thought process of the coder (what you imagine is happening in abstract visual code/high level definition of the code)
- API's
- Psuedocode
- Source code
- Links to content that explains topics similar to this

However, these are just guidelines to the type of answer I'm looking for. Just keep in mind, I am not interested in that site alone, but more of the coding ideas and concepts behind the abstract visual programs. I hope I made sense of what I am confused/interested in. I will gladly clarify if anyone has questions on what I am asking. Thank you in advance for your replies!

Edit: To further define the ideas that I am interested in, here is an article on an interesting visual rendering: http://www.iquilezles.org/www/articles/warp/warp.htm

Answer (score 1):

For the nkwiatek.com example, I would start like that:

- Create some JavaScript function that makes characters follow the mouse. It could be for example a simple shape like that at first:

```
  OOO
 OOOOO
 OOOOO
  OOO
```

- Once this is working, make it leave a trail and keep a reference to each characters that's been added to the screen (will be needed later)
- Now make each generated character semi-random and use the previously mentioned reference to constantly update the characters on screen. The further away a character is from the mouse, the smaller it should look. i.e. characters near the mouse could be "big" like AMHIJKL, etc. characters further away could be smaller like -~=, etc. and ., etc. for the most further away.

This should already make a nice animation. After that, I think there's some function that makes everything move in a kind of wave. It seems to be based on the velocity of the mouse. Maybe there's some research paper on how to generate such an effect.

Answer (score 0):

That is one amazing background.

How to start? Go to the web page and hit Ctrl+U. It's Javascript, so the source is right there. From that... study. The guy's code looks pretty clear, but of course what he's DOING is complicated so it will take some time. Time well spent, I'd think.

Higher-level things like what the guy was thinking... you'll know that after studying the code.